# Openmp. How to retrieve the core id in which a thread is running

Tags: c, openmp

I've set KMP_AFFINITY to scatter but the execution time increased a lot!

That's why I think that OpenMP is spawning threads on only 1 core.

So I need something
that returns which core a thread is using at the moment.

This is the pragma I'm using before the for loop:

```
int procs = omp_get_num_procs();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(procs)\
shared (c, u, v, w, k, j, i, nx, ny) \
reduction(+: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)
```

And these are the exports I did:

```
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=5
export KMP_AFFINITY=verbose,scatter
```

If it helps I'm pasting also the verbose:

```
OMP: Info #149: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid instr info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 8 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #159: KMP_AFFINITY: 2 packages x 4 cores/pkg x 1 threads/core (8 total cores)
OMP: Info #160: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map ([] => level not in map):
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0 core 0 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 4 maps to package 0 core 1 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 2 maps to package 0 core 2 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 6 maps to package 0 core 3 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 1 maps to package 1 core 0 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 5 maps to package 1 core 1 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 3 maps to package 1 core 2 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #168: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 7 maps to package 1 core 3 [thread 0]
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 0 bound to OS proc set {0}
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 1 bound to OS proc set {1}
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 2 bound to OS proc set {4}
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 3 bound to OS proc set {5}
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 4 bound to OS proc set {2}
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 5 bound to OS proc set {3}
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 6 bound to OS proc set {6}
OMP: Info #147: KMP_AFFINITY: Internal thread 7 bound to OS proc set {7}
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: Variables declared before the parallel region are shared by default. You don't have any `private` clause and therefore it is possible that lots of variables you think are private are actually shared. Data races and false sharing can greatly degrade program's performance and make you think that all threads run on a single core.

Comment: The verbose listing you show does not seem to correspond to the run you claim to be making, since it shows eight OpenMP threads, which (you can see) are each bound to a separate logical CPU, whereas you claimed to be running with five threads. (So it definitely *is* using all the hardware). You haven't said what the base case is, only that scatter is slower than ...something... In your machine it's possible that four threads all in one socket could easily be faster than four threads in two sockets if there's a lot of data sharing.

Comment: p.s. If you don't trust the output from the runtime that shows what it is doing, and assuming you're on Linux you could simply run xosview and see the load on each of your logical CPUs as you run your code.

Comment: That's true. I was using omp_get_num_procs() instead of omp_get_max_threads() that's why it was spawning always 8 threads (cause it has 8 cores). I've fixed that but I'm still facing the same results :(

Answer (score 11):

As @user3018144 [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22493436/1800052), `sched_getcpu(3)` is what can be used to obtain CPU number.

Consider the following code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE // sched_getcpu(3) is glibc-specific (see the man page)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int thread_num = omp_get_thread_num();
        int cpu_num = sched_getcpu();
        printf("Thread %3d is running on CPU %3d\n", thread_num, cpu_num);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my output without affinity:

```
$> OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out | sort
Thread   0 is running on CPU   2
Thread   1 is running on CPU   0
Thread   2 is running on CPU   3
Thread   3 is running on CPU   1
```

And this is the output with affinity:

```
$> GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY='0,1,2,3' OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out | sort
Thread   0 is running on CPU   0
Thread   1 is running on CPU   1
Thread   2 is running on CPU   2
Thread   3 is running on CPU   3
```

Comment: This works for me too, but I am getting a warning: `implicit declaration of function ‘sched_getcpu’; did you mean ‘sched_getparam’?` from every compiler I used.

Comment: @RobertSawko, use `#define _GNU_SOURCE` in the code or compile with `-D_GNU_SOURCE`. The reason is that `sched_getcpu(3)` is glibc-specific. I've updated the answer with this information.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on linux, you might use the function `sched_getcpu()`. Here is a link to explain how it works and its declaration:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html

Hope this can help

Comment: Hello. I already tried to use this function. But it reported undefined function sched_getcpu. I think that's it since I'm using Intel's Compiler.

Comment: @CrashLaker, it's rather because you've probably forgot to add `#include <sched.h>` somewhere at the top of your code.

Comment: I didn't forget to include <sched.h>. I guess that this library doesn't exists. But if that's the case shouldn't c compiler warn me about that?

Comment: I tried a test program with intel compiler and it perfectly works so you might check your code, you should have an error somewhere.

Comment: `sched.h` should be in `usr/include/`

Comment: Or try to put at the top of your file: `#define _GNU_SOURCE`